# mkfs fails on ec2 t3.large instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef

I would like to move to t3 instances from t2 instances on ec2 but my chef deployment script fails on t3 instances but works on t2 instances running under either ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04.

I can create and attach an ec2 volume successfully but creating the filesystem fails with: mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdf

saying: The file /dev/sdf does not exist and no size was specified.

I can verify in the web console that the volume is created and attached to the instance and available as /dev/sdf.

Is there a change with t3 instances that I need to be aware of?

Thank

Comment: Doesn't it provide the volume as `xvdf`?

Comment: Please show the output of `lsblk`

Comment: Hi here is the output from lsblk:

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop1         7:1    0 12.7M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
nvme0n1     259:0    0   30G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   30G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0   50G  0 disk

Comment: @BlueSkies your `lsblk` output confirms the answer below - your new 50GB disk is `/dev/nvme1n1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my `t3.large` the root disk is shown as `/dev/xvda` in the console but accessible as `/dev/nvme0n1` from Linux.

The second disk (`/dev/xvdb` in the aws console) is called `/dev/nvme1n1` with partitions `/dev/nvme1n1p1` and `/dev/nvme1n1p2`.

Perhaps your system instance will have similar names?

In that case to create new partitions run `fdisk /dev/nvme1n1` and go ahead with your partitioning.

Hope that helps :)